# How to reference other locations in making multi-boot live cd

Tags: linux, usb, multi-boot, usb-flash-drive

There is a tool in pen drive linux that allows you to boot directly with multiple iso files. 
And here is a sample in the menu.lst which allows you to choose which iso file you want to boot.

```
title Fedora 12
find --set-root /Fedora-12-i686-L.iso
map /Fedora-12-i686-L.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso splash
initrd /casper/initrd.lz
```

I'm just using it on my 8gb flash drive and the location of the iso file is in the flash drive itself. Is it possible to reference other locations. So that I could boot from it, without limitations. because the flash drive can only contain 8gb of data.
Is it possible? Anyone here tried this before?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to boot from?  other ISO files on the flash drive? other drives?

Comment: I'm trying to boot from the flash drive. But I want to reference other drives for the location of the iso files.